# Problems with setting up an enum type

Tags: java, enums

I'm trying to do a project from school in which I'm creating my own objects, along with private data, methods, etc. This isn’t a complete working system with a user interface; it’s just a chance to create classes, then instantiate and test them.

The fictional business in the project Dina’s Dinettes who is selling one type of dinette set. An order consists of one table, zero to ten chairs, and zero to two leaves. The customer also gets one free item with their order, either (1) a cleaning kit, (2) seat cushions, or (3) padded feet for the table and chairs. The code you’ll write is the start of a system to create and process orders, and maintain store inventories.

One issue I'm having is I'm trying to set up the "option" setting which is assumed to be a enum type. I thought I could set up the enum value as private data along with the orderNumber, chairCount, and leafCount values, but I'm getting a lot of "cannot find symbol" errors. Here is what I've done so far:

```
public class DinetteOrder
{
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   //      STATIC CONSTANTS
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------



   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   //      PRIVATE INSTANCE DATA
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   private int orderNumber;
   private int chairCount;
   private int leafCount;
   private enum option {cleanKit, seatCush, padFeet};

   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   //      CONSTRUCTORS
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

   public DinetteOrder(){
       orderNumber = 0;
       chairCount = 0;
       leafCount = 0;
       option = 0;
   }

   public DinetteOrder(int orderNumber, int chairCount, int leafCount, option option){
       this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
       this.chairCount = chairCount;
       this.leafCount = leafCount;
       this.option = option;
   }

   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   //      ASSESSORS
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

   public int orderNumer(){
       return orderNumber;
    }

   public int getChairCount(){
       return chairCount;
   }

   public int getLeafCount(){
       return leafCount;
    }

   public option getOption(){
       return option;
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //      MUTATORS
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void setChairCount(int chairCount) {
        this.chairCount = chairCount;
    }

    public void setLeafCount(int leafCount) {
        this.leafCount = leafCount;
    }

    public void setOption(Option option) {
        this.option = Option;
    }


    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //      OTHER METHODS
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public double getPrice(int DinetteOrder) {
        double getPrice = 219.00 + (59.00 * chairCount) + (35.00 * leafCount);
        return getPrice;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Table Count: 1\n Chair Count: " + chairCount + "\n Leaf Count: " + leafCount + "\n";
    }

}
```

Any input as to what I've did wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've defined an `option` enum but not an `option` instance variable.

This:

```
private enum option {cleanKit, seatCush, padFeet};
```

Should probably be turned into:

```
public enum Option {cleanKit, seatCush, padFeet};
private Option option;
```

And your constructor changed to:

```
public DinetteOrder(int orderNumber, int chairCount, int leafCount, Option option) {
   this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
   this.chairCount = chairCount;
   this.leafCount = leafCount;
   this.option = option;
}
```

Note the use of capital "O" for the enum type and small "o" for the instance variable and constructor parameter name. Additionally, your first constructor cannot assign `0` as the `option`; it will need to be one of the enum values.